# Flexbox with responsive iframe youtube videos

Tags: html, css, firefox, flexbox

I'm working on a website to add youtube videos over three `<iframe>`. I would like that the videos are next to each other and that they are responsive.

It's working fine on Chrome and IE, but not working on Firefox. Anybody have a clue?

```css
.video-media-youtube-inner {
  display: flex;
}

.video-media-youtube-inner-vi01 {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  height: 0;
}

.video-media-youtube-inner-vi01 iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-media-youtube">
  <div class="video-media-youtube-inner">
    <div class="video-media-youtube-inner-vi01">
      <iframe></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="video-media-youtube-inner-vi02">
      <iframe></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="video-media-youtube-inner-vi03">
      <iframe></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: remove `height:0`

Comment: unfortunately did not help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should set all three flex items to `flex: 1` or `flex: 0 0 33.3333%`.

```
.video-media-youtube-inner-vi01,
.video-media-youtube-inner-vi02,
.video-media-youtube-inner-vi03 {
  flex: 1;
}
```

Or

```
div[class^="video-media-youtube-inner-vi"] {
  flex: 1;
}
```

Comment: love the avatar and name! :)